# Map method to effect all EXCEPT last array item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a challenge that takes in a string, then returns the string in all caps, a few replacements/substitutions for vowels, and has "!!!!" after each word.

```
function gordon(a){
return a.split(" ").map(function(x){return x.replace(/[aA]/g,"@").replace(/[aeiou]/g,"*") + "!!!! ";}).join("").toUpperCase();

}
```

This code works, and returns the right answer, except for ONE whitespace at the end of the last "!!!".

The main reason I'm asking this is because this is something that I feel like I run into a lot with the map method or for loops. What do you do if you want to affect all elements except the last one? Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try using reduce instead of map

Comment: I don't see where the extra whitespace is coming from. Does the input string have a space at the end? Try trimming it before you split it.

Comment: @Rastalamm I tried using reduce and it is only returning the first element in the array as the answer with all the "!!!" behind it.

Comment: @barmar My mistake! I edited my code with the whitespace. I need white space after each returned word, but not on the LAST word. Thats the issue I'm running into...

Comment: `map` takes a callback function. That function takes [three parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the current value, the index, and the array. You should be able to deduce from the last two whether you are on the last element or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want space *between* the words after joining, put that in the `.join()` call instead of after `!!!!`.

```
function gordon(a){
    return a.split(" ")
        .map(function(x){
            return x.replace(/[aA]/g,"@").replace(/[aeiou]/g,"*") + "!!!!";
        })
        .join(" ")
        .toUpperCase();
}
```

The argument to `.join()` is the separator put between each array element when they're concatenated into the result string.

Comment: Right, and this works. But what I'm trying to get rid of is the space *after* the LAST "!!!" while keeping all the other spaces....

Comment: Why get rid of it if you can avoid adding it in the first place?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I know what you mean, I'm sorry. Maybe there is a better way to approach this that I'm not thinking of. When I pass in a string to the 'a' parameter in the function I want to split each string into words, then after doing my edits, i wanted to join() them with a space in between each word but NOT after the *last* word. So if I passed gordon("what are you doing"), it would return "WH@T!!!! @R*!!!! Y**!!!! D*ING!!!!".  I need the "!!!!" after each word and a space in between them but *not* the space after "D*ING!!!".

Comment: The reason your have an extra space is because you have a space at the end of `"!!!! "`, and you're appending that to each word. Instead, you should use `.join(" ")` to put the spaces in between the words, not after each word.

Comment: Then there's nothing to remove, because you never added the space.

Comment: You could also use `.trim()` on the final result to remove any extra spaces around it.

Comment: Right, but I need spaces in between each "!!!". After each word there is "!!!" *then* a space. so I need Word!!! (space) Word!!! (space) Word!!! (space) LastWord!!!(no space). if I remove the space from the "!!!" in the function it looks like this: Word!!!Word!!!Word!!!Word!!!. I need those spaces in between, but not after the last one. Am I making sense?

Comment: `.join(" ")` puts a space in between each word when it joins them together.

Comment: Why is this difficult to understand? It's the opposite of `.split(" ")`.

Comment: Gotcha. I wasn't putting the space with`join(" ")`. I was doing `join("")`. Good to know. Thanks a lot for your help man!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to javascript methods. It was a small detail I missed. I figured the space in the parenthesis didn't matter for some reason. thanks again for your help and time.